# Consider the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$, what is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr 2 \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, semidirect-product, infinite-groups, wreath-product

Consider the (Lamplighter) group $(\bigoplus_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z}$, where $\phi(1)$ "shifts" every element in $\bigoplus_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2$ to the right by $1$. I was wondering if its subgroup, $(\bigoplus_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes_\phi2 \mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to a wreath product of a finite abelian group with $\mathbb{Z}$.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z} \not \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \wr 2 \mathbb{Z}$. However,  $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr 2 \mathbb{Z}$ is a wreath product of a finite abelian group with a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, does that implies that it is isomorphic to a wreath product of a finite abelian group by $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What does “$\,\wr\,$” mean ? I do not know what it is.

Comment: I guess by $Z_2 \wr 2Z$, you mean the obvious subgroup of index $2$ in $Z_2 \wr Z$? If so, then yes, it is isomorphic to $(Z_2 \oplus Z_2) \wr Z$.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt

Comment: @Angelo (standard) wreath product.